# Difference between Enum and IntEnum in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, enums, integer

I came across a code that looked like this:

```
class State(IntEnum):
    READY = 1
    IN_PROGRESS = 2
    FINISHED = 3
    FAILED = 4
```

and I came to the conclusion that this State class could inherit the `Enum` class in the same way.

What does inheriting from `IntEnum` gives me that inheriting from the regular class `Enum` won't? What is the difference between them?

Comment: Well, @DeepSpace, I read the docs but all was written was that `Base class for creating enumerated constants that are also subclasses of int.`. This doesn't tell you why should you use one over the other, even thought one is more suitable for me. I found the use case and the explanation of @mehrdad-pedramfar very helpful.

Comment: One benefit is IntEnum allows sorting by default, Enum does not by default.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

From the python [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html):

> Enum: Base class for creating enumerated constants.

and:

> IntEnum: Base class for creating enumerated constants that are also subclasses of int.

it says that members of an `IntEnum` can be compared to integers; by extension, integer enumerations of different types can also be compared to each other.

look at the below example:

```
class Shape(IntEnum):
    CIRCLE = 1
    SQUARE = 2

class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2

Shape.CIRCLE == Color.RED
>> False

Shape.CIRCLE == 1
>>True
```

and they will behave same as an integer:

```
['a', 'b', 'c'][Shape.CIRCLE]
>> 'b'
```

Comment: Well, if you already read the docs for the  OP, perhaps the most obvious example for a difference between `Enum` and `IntEnum` will be that `Color.RED < Color.GREEN` will raise a `TypeError` while `Shape.CIRCLE < Shape.SQUARE` will not.

Comment: @DeepSpace Sure, I add the last part that said they act like integers for the same purpose. and there is a couple of more examples that we can explain here. thanks for saying, man.

Answer (score 8):

IntEnum is used to ensure that members must be integer i.e.

```py
class State(IntEnum):
    READY = 'a'
    IN_PROGRESS = 'b'
    FINISHED = 'c'
    FAILED = 'd'
```

This will raise an exception:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

Comment: I wouldn't consider this the primary difference. Ensuring that the member values are integers is a constraint rather than a feature, because `IntEnum` provides direct comparison with integers (that `Enum` doesn't do, you have to access the `.value` property). This can only happen properly if the values are integers, so the class checks this for you.

Answer (score 2):

`intEnum` give the following advantages:

1. It ensures the members must be integer:

   ```
   ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10
   ```

   will be raise if this is not satisfied.
2. It allows comparison with integer:

   ```py
   import enum

   class Shape(enum.IntEnum):
       CIRCLE = 1
       SQUARE = 2

   class Color(enum.Enum):
       RED = 1
       GREEN = 2

   print(Shape.CIRCLE == 1)
   # >> True

   print(Color.RED == 1)
   # >> False
   ```