# Enums in Python not converting to numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, enumeration

The below code works fine if I replace `end_day=WeekDay.SUN` with `end_day=6`. I am not sure if I understand Enum usage properly.

```
from enum import Enum, unique
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

@unique
class WeekDay(Enum):
     MON = 0
     TUE = 1
     WED = 2
     THU = 3
     FRI = 4
     SAT = 5
     SUN = 6

def get_alldates(start_date, end_date, end_day=WeekDay.SUN):
    all_dts = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='d')
    weekday_dts = [x for x in all_dts if pd.to_datetime(x).weekday() == end_day]
    return weekday_dts

>>> get_alldates(datetime(2021,7,1), datetime(2021,9,1))
[]
```

I thought `WeekDay.SUN` will be processed as number 6. But its not. And replacing `end_day=WeekDay.SUN` with `end_day=6` works like a charm.

```
>>> get_alldates(datetime(2021,7,1), datetime(2021,9,1))
[Timestamp('2021-07-04 00:00:00', freq='D'), Timestamp('2021-07-11 00:00:00', freq='D'), Timestamp('2021-07-18 00:00:00', freq='D'), Timestamp('2021-07-25 00:00:00', freq='D'), Timestamp('2021-08-01 00:00:00', freq='D'), Timestamp('2021-08-08 00:00:00', freq='D'), Timestamp('2021-08-15 00:00:00', freq='D'), Timestamp('2021-08-22 00:00:00', freq='D'), Timestamp('2021-08-29 00:00:00', freq='D')]
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Try adding `value` after `Weekday.SUN`.

Comment: @norie you mean `end_day.value`?

Comment: No `Weekday.SUN.value`.

Comment: That works but I dont follow why `end_day.value` or simply `end_day` won't work.

Comment: To be honest, I don't either - seems kind of strange. Someone asked the same question here https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/8oisf2/why_do_enums_require_you_access_the_values_with/

Comment: Use IntEnum instead: [Difference between Enum and IntEnum in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52929954/difference-between-enum-and-intenum-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Enums do not convert to numbers because enums are not numbers -- they are names.  They can be, and usually are, backed by numbers, and those numbers can be accessed with the `.value` attribute.

Note that the backing value does not have to be a number -- it can be a `str`, a `tuple`, a `dict`, etc.

If you need your enum members to act like numbers, then you need to inherit from the appropriate data type:

```
class WeekDay(int, Enum):
    pass
```

then `WeekDay.SUN == 6` will be `True`.